# Why can't we have current class reference holding the super class object?

Tags: java, class, inheritance

Lets say If there are two classes A and B, where A extends B so by convention A can access B's members which are not private. So why can't we create an object of B and assign that reference to A.

**Class A:**

```
public class A extends B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        A a = new B();          
        B b = new A();          
    }    
}
```

**Class B:**

```
public class B { 

}
```

My main question is :

1. Why `A a = new B();` is incorrect?
2. Why `B b = new A();` is correct?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a

Comment: Because you can have a hand A consisting of 5 fingers B, but never a Finger B consisting of 5 hands A. It‘s simply illogical. It's all about the way inheritance goes. And Java mimics this principle.

Comment: @DiabolicWords yep make sense.

Comment: Make a more concrete example. `Dog extends Animal`. It's clear that you can do `Animal a = new Dog();` but not the other way around since there could be different animal too, like a `Cat` which is not a `Dog`.

Comment: There must be a *really good* dupetarger for this... That said, this is the most clearly-asked version I've seen (change the class names and it's **really** clear).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So why can't we create an object of B and assign that reference to A.
>
> 1) Why `A a = new B();` is incorrect?

Because `A` also (potentially) has features `B` doesn't have, so the instance (which is a `B`) *isn't* an `A`, so you can't assign a `B` instance to an `A`-typed variable.

> 2) Why `B b = new A();` is correct?

Because instances of `A` **are** `B` instances, they just may also be a bit more than `B` instances. So it's fine (and common) for a `B`-typed variable to refer to an `A` instance. Remember, inheritance is an "is a" relationship. `A extends B` means an `A` instance *is a* `B` instance.

Let's use more meaningful class names and include some state:

```
class Super {
    private int foo;
    // ...details omitted...
}

class Sub extends Super {
    private int bar;
    // ...details omitted...
}
```

So an instance of `Super` has a data slot for `foo`:

```
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
| (Super instance) |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
| foo: 0           |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

An instance of `Sub` has a slot for `foo` (because it *is a* `Super`) and also a slot for `bar`:

```
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
|  (Sub instance)  |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
| foo: 0           |
| bar: 0           |
+−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

A variable of type `Super` can refer to a `Sub` instance; the instance has all the data slots (and behavior, not shown) that a `Super` has. But a variable of type `Sub` cannot refer to a `Super` instance; the instance doesn't have the `bar` data slot (and potentially `Sub`-specific behaviors, not shown).

Comment: @TechnocratSid So mark this answer as accpeted,please

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a superclass instance to a variable because you might run into a situation where you want to e.g. call a method from the subclass.

At compile time and at runtime you would run into the same problem: What shall happen if a method from the subclass is called on the variable of type subclass while it holds a type superclass? The superclass does not necessarily have all fields and methods from the subclass.

The other way it works, because everything the superclass has, the subclass also has.